# Showing that a limit does not exist

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I am to show that the following limit
$$\lim_{x \to \pi} 2^{\frac{1}{\sin(x)}}$$
does not exist.

I would like to solve this problem using the Heine definition of a limit. Saying that I have chosen two sequences
$$x_n = \pi - \frac{1}{n}, \qquad y_n = \pi + \frac{1}{n}.$$

Of course $x_n \to \pi$ and $y_n \to \pi$. More precisely we have $x_n \to \pi^-$ and $y_n \to \pi^+$ thus $\sin(x_n) \to 0^+$ and $\sin(y_n) \to 0^-$.

Having that we can write that
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{\frac{1}{\sin(x_n)}} = \infty$$
and
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{\frac{1}{\sin(y_n)}} = 0.$$

To sum up we managed to point sequences which do not satisfy the Heine definition thus this limit does not exist. Is my solution correct? I'm a bit confused with the following parts $x_n \to \pi$ and $y_n \to \pi$.

Comment: I'm guessing there's a typo on the second limit with $x_n$ instead of $y_n$, but even then that second limit should be $0$ and not $-\infty$ (since it's $1/\sin(y_n)$ that diverges to $-\infty$ not $2$ elevated at that power). However, this doesn't change the result, your solution is indeed correct.

Comment: No, no. $2^{\text{something}}$ is positive, so its limit can never be $-\infty$.

Comment: Exactly @ajotatxe, that's one immediate way to see that the limit was wrong, but in the end it thankfully didn't matter since the actual limit is still not the first limit $+\infty$.

Comment: The second one should be $\lim_{n \to \infty} 2^{\frac{1}{\sin(y_n)}} = 2^{-\infty}=0$

Comment: Sorry! That was a typo of course.